# OffcanvasMenu plugin - click event, Shopware 6

Tags: javascript, shopware

I have a problem with adding a click event for list of OffcanvasMenu. I need add this event for every li element. I'm working with Shopware 6.
But when I'm trying to add click event for li element with jQuery, nothing happens.
I've extended OffcanvasMenu. Here is my code:

```
import OffcanvasMenuPlugin from 'src/plugin/main-menu/offcanvas-menu.plugin.js';

export default class ExtendOffcanvasMenuPlugin extends OffcanvasMenuPlugin {
    init() {
        super.init();
        this._registerEvents();
        console.log("inner");
    }

    _registerEvents() {
        super._registerEvents();

        let list = document.querySelector('.navigation-offcanvas-list-item');

        console.log(list);

        list.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            console.log("inner event");
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
}
```

In  main.js file I overriding this plugin:

```
PluginManager.override('OffcanvasMenu', ExtendOffcanvasMenuPlugin, '[data-offcanvas-menu]');
```

It's any possibility to add event on every li element in OffcanvasMenu plugin?

Answer (score 2):

the general problem seems to be that the current code is using `querySelector` to collect all elements. However `querySelector` does only yield *the first element* which matches the selector, even if there are multiple ones, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

You can solve this by using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which does essentially the same but returns an iterable list of all found elements. Then you can iterate over the list and attach the listener to each element:

```js
import OffcanvasMenuPlugin from 'src/plugin/main-menu/offcanvas-menu.plugin.js';

export default class ExtendOffcanvasMenuPlugin extends OffcanvasMenuPlugin {
    _registerEvents() {
        super._registerEvents();

        let list = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation-offcanvas-list-item');

        console.log(list);

        list.forEach((listItem) => {
            listItem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                console.log("inner event");
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This would work in theory but in practice the `a.navigation-offcanvas-link` is inside the `<li>` where you want to attach the listener. The `a.navigation-offcanvas-link` element has already an event listener (`_getLinkEventHandler`) and also takes up all the space inside the `<li>` which is why the `<li>` itself is not actually clickable.

A workaround could be to make remove the listener first from `a.navigation-offcanvas-link` and make it non-clickable but it depends on what you want to achieve. Should something additional be executed everytime a menu item is being clicked? Then you could consider extending method `_getLinkEventHandler` directly even though it is marked as private and might change in future versions.